# C++ Update vector elements through iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator

I am implementing in-place merge sort, so I need to update the vector container elements without creating a new container. I am iterating through the container, and do not have the vector container as parameter. I am only passing the iterator of targeted container.

My question is "how do I update or replace vector container elements only through iterator of that vector container?"

The following is part of my code.

```
  template<typename T>
  void it_practice(T begin, T end) {

  for(T it = begin; it != end; ++it)
  {
        if (R_half[j] >= L_half[i])
        {
              *it = L_half[i];
              i++;
        }
        else
        {
              *it = R_half[j];
              j++;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`*it` gives you a reference to the according element, and that reference can be assigned to. Iterators behave similar to pointers, keep that in mind.

Comment: right, iterator is for referencing, so how do I access to the original using referencing? Dereferencing is only for retrieving the value.

Comment: Oh right. I was doing what I was trying to do. I forgot to divide the container recursively. Thanks!